# A specific problem on the calculation of the expected value of an expression with 2 RVs

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expectation, independence

Let $a$ and $\phi$ be independent random variables, each with a known probability density function. Furthermore, in the sequences of observations $(a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{N})$ all $a_{i}$ are independent and identically distributed. Similarly, in the sequence of observations $(\phi_{1},\phi_{2},...,\phi_{N})$ all $\phi_{i}$ are independent and identically distributed.

The goal is to calculate $E[P]$ where $P$ is given by:

$$P=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}a_{i}a_{j}\cos\left(\phi_{i}-\phi_{j}\right)$$

Here's what I came up with so far:

$$P = \sum_{i=1}^{N}a_{i}^{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^{N}a_{i}a_{j}\cos\left(\phi_{i}-\phi_{j}\right)$$

$$E[P]=\sum_{i=1}^{N} E[a_{i}^{2}] + \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^{N}E[a_{i}a_{j}\times \cos(\phi_{i}-\phi_{j})]$$

because $a$ and $\phi$ are independent RVs we can write:

$$E[P] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} E[a_{i}^{2}] + \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^{N}E[a_{i}a_{j}] E[\cos(\phi_{i}-\phi_{j})]$$

because the $a$ sequence is $iid$ we can write:

$$E[P] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} E[a^{2}] + \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1,j\neq i}^{N}E[a]E[a] E[\cos(\phi_{i}-\phi_{j})]$$

and finally:
$$E[P] = N E[a^{2}] + N(N-1) E[a]^{2} E[\cos(\phi_{i}-\phi_{j})]$$

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $